# How can I move between the data grid view cells when I press the Enter button?

Tags: c#

I would like to thank you at the beginning, then can you help me? It is known that when moving between the data grid view cells, we press the tab button to do this. I would like to do the same work but by pressing the Enter button

Comment: [Control.KeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Add tag.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov WinForms -> *"data grid view cells"*